# How can I filter by value in ng-repeat(key, value) and only display if the value is not null?

Tags: angularjs, key-value, ng-filter

I have an object with multiple properties, and I want to filter out the properties that are empty. Most of the properties are not required, and can be null. I cannot figure how to make a filter for that.

```
<div class="hero-unit" ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedItem | valueNotNull">
                            <span class="hero-title">{{key|insertSpaces}} : </span>     
                            <span class="hero-content">{{ value }}</span>
```

When the value of the property is null or empty I do not want to diplay the hero unit for that specific property. And still show the rest of the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the empty values

Try like this

```
<div class="hero-unit" ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedItem" ng-hide="!value">
                            <span class="hero-title">{{key|insertSpaces}} : </span>     
                            <span class="hero-content">{{ value }}</span>
```

Comment: Modified this by passing value as parameter to check for another condition other than `!truthy` and solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `ng-if`:

```
<div class="hero-unit" ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedItem | valueNotNull"
     ng-if="value">
    <span class="hero-title">{{key|insertSpaces}} : </span>     
    <span class="hero-content">{{ value }}</span>
</div>
```

This would hide `<div>` key value pairs where the `value` be not truthy (i.e. is null, undefined, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="hero-unit" ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedItem | filter:{value:''}">
                            <span class="hero-title">{{key|insertSpaces}} : </span>     
                            <span class="hero-content">{{ value }}</span>
```

You should check it with filter (value you want to not be null).